# I am working on a php docker application.Am facing an error while trying docker-compose up command

Tags: java, linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    web:
    build: .
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
redis:
   image: "redis:alpine"
```

my err :

```
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'build' must be a mapping not a string.
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you are not using TABs, but just SPACEs ( YAML does not support TABS)
- Also, You have wrong indentation in your YAML file:

it should be:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Comment: thank you a lot ,it's working

Comment: Happy to help! Please mark it as solution to help others to know that.